# What was authWithPassword replaced with in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication login with Email and password and I'm following a Github sample example on how to implement it in your current app. Apparently, the method "**authWithPassword**" has been removed and I could not find any comments in the firebase.auth library on if it was deprecated and with what it has been replaced with? Can anyone provide some insights on the subject?

Comment: Check this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been replaced with [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). However, the method is no longer on a Firebase reference, instead it is on a `FirebaseAuth` instance:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("some-email", "some-password").addOnCompleteListener(...);
```

There is a migration guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_authentication_code_numbered).

Comment: How different createUserWithEmailAndPassword is from signInWithEmailAndPassword?

Comment: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` creates a new user account using the supplied credentials and signs in the user (if the account creation succeeds). `signInWithEmailAndPassword` will only sign in a user to an existing account.